# Is the Modern Experience more consistently implemented in Subscription Edition (final GA version)?

Tags: sharepoint-server, modern-experience, sharepoint-on-prem

With the [General Availability of SharePoint Server Subscription Edition now announced](https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2021/11/02/sharepoint-server-subscription-edition-spse-general-availability-has-been-announced/), I'm curious if anyone has anyone had time to test it? I am mainly interested to know if the Modern Experience has been implemented for more list templates and in a more consistent manner across the product than was the case with SP2019?

Microsoft has not indicated anything about that on the ["New and improved features](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-s-new/new-and-improved-features-in-sharepoint-server-subscription-edition)" pages...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there has been some improvements, Site Templates/Site Scripts are not part of this release. They may be included in a future update depending on customer demand vs. engineering effort.

As for the SPFx webparts included, there have been some improvements there, as well. But don't expect an SPO-like experience as this code base (unlike 2019) was not forked from SPO.

Comment: Thanks for sharing those interesting insights, Trevor. Can you elaborate some more on the code base part? I was under the impression that each new server release would get progressively more cloud developed stuff. But I am slowly starting to realize that the server releases are more like small, very selected, crumbs dropping from the cloud table. :) (Of course I knew that all along, but it's unfortunately even less than I'd hoped.)